# Connect to Azure IotHub using MQTT in Javascript

Tags: node.js, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, sasl

I keep getting back `Connection refused: Not authorized` when trying to connect to the Azure IotHub using `MQTT.js` (https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js).

The SAS password is generated using Microsoft Device Explorer (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer) so providing the right read/write connection details along with an expiry date in the future, I am assuming it is correct and valid.

I am also requiring TLS/SSL to be enabled (as per Microsoft Azure documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#tlsssl-configuration) via `rejectUnauthorized: false` (as explained in the documentation for MQTT.js at https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#client).

**How do I connect via Javascript using a 3rd party MQTT library and a SAS token?**

This is a snippet of the Javascript code:

```
var MQTT = require("async-mqtt");

const deviceId = "<PUT_SOMETHING_HERE>";
const iotHubName = "<PUT_SOMETHING_HERE>";

const url = `${iotHubName}.azure-devices.net/${deviceId}/api-version=2016-11-14`;
const iotHubTopic = `devices/${deviceId}/messages/events/`

var client = MQTT.connect(`mqtts://${url}:8883`, {
  username: url,
  password: `SharedAccessSignature sr=${iotHubName}.azure-devices.net&sig=<COMBINATION_OF_PASSWORDS_URL_ENCODED>&se=<EPOCH_EXPIRY>&skn=<ACCESS_POLICY_NAME>`,
  rejectUnauthorized: false, // https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#client
});

// this is code from the MQTT.js example, but I don't even reach it
async function doStuff() {

    console.log("Starting");
    try {
        await client.publish(iotHubTopic, "It works!");
        // This line doesn't run until the server responds to the publish
        await client.end();
        // This line doesn't run until the client has disconnected without error
        console.log("Done");
    } catch (e){
        // Do something about it!
        console.log("Error while sending a message...");
        console.log(e.stack);
        process.exit();
    }
}

const ceremony = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      client.on("connect", doStuff);
      return resolve();
    })
    .then((stuff) => {
      console.log("Done?", stuff);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Err...", err);
      process.exit();
    });
}

ceremony();
```

The output is this:

```
Done? undefined
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection refused: Not authorized
    at MqttClient._handleConnack (<PATH_TO_THE_JS_PROJECT>/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:896:15)
    at MqttClient._handlePacket (<PATH_TO_THE_JS_PROJECT>/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:332:12)
    at work (<PATH_TO_THE_JS_PROJECT>/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:274:12)
    at Writable.writable._write (<PATH_TO_THE_JS_PROJECT>/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:284:5)
    at doWrite (<PATH_TO_THE_JS_PROJECT>/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:428:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (<PATH_TO_THE_JS_PROJECT>/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:417:5)
    at Writable.write (<PATH_TO_THE_JS_PROJECT>/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:334:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:639:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
```

Comment: Why not use the [IoT Hub Device SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iot-device)? 3rd party MQTT libs are kind of a hit-and-miss with Azure IoT Hub, since it's not a _real_ broker (at least it's not meant to be used like that).

Comment: Just tried it out and, indeed, it throws unauthenticated for MQTTS but works over Websockets, with `var client = MQTT.connect(\`wss://${url}\`,...`

Comment: Nope, spoke too soon. Hangs on `wss://`.

Comment: @evilSnobu I've a requirement to use MQTT (no AMQP or other protocols) and I was trying to avoid including code that I won't be using e.g. that IoT Hub SDK includes code for different protocols that I don't need. Also: plain MQTT is a valid option in the IoT Hub official documentation.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could only import this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iot-device-mqtt. For the `Message` type, you can just borrow the code from the [`azure-iot-common` lib](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/common/core/src/message.ts).

Comment: I am trying to stick to the MQTT protocol, if I end up using a different broker then I can hope to reuse most of the code instead of starting again with yet another MQTT flavor. According to the official Azure IoT Hub docs MQTT is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly

Comment: It is, and it should work. I would open an issue here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node. If you only need an MQTT broker i'd probably just deploy Mosquitto in a 2-node Kubernetes cluster or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Azure IoT Hub supports MQTT, you can use MQTT protocol to connect with the IoT Hub directly, and publish/subscribe the topics as send/receive messages with the documented topic names and topic filters. I have modified the above code, and it works fine.

```
var MQTT = require("async-mqtt");

const deviceId = "{the device name}";
const iotHubName = "{your iot hub name}";
const userName = `${iotHubName}.azure-devices.net/${deviceId}/api-version=2016-11-14`;
const iotHubTopic = `devices/${deviceId}/messages/events/`;

var client = MQTT.connect(`mqtts://${iotHubName}.azure-devices.net:8883`, {
  keepalive: 10,
  clientId: deviceId,
  protocolId: 'MQTT',
  clean: false,
  protocolVersion: 4,
  reconnectPeriod: 1000,
  connectTimeout: 30 * 1000,
  username: userName,
  password: "{SAS Token}",
  rejectUnauthorized: false, 
});

// this is code from the MQTT.js example, but I don't even reach it
async function doStuff() {

    console.log("Starting");
    try {
        await client.publish(iotHubTopic, "It works!");
        // This line doesn't run until the server responds to the publish
        await client.end();
        // This line doesn't run until the client has disconnected without error
        console.log("Done");
    } catch (e){
        // Do something about it!
        console.log("Error while sending a message...");
        console.log(e.stack);
        process.exit();
    }
}

const ceremony = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      client.on("connect", doStuff);
      return resolve();
    })
    .then((stuff) => {
      console.log("Done?", stuff);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Err...", err);
      process.exit();
    });
}

ceremony();
```

In the code, you need to note that:

1. Use **DEVICE ID** in IoT Hub as clientId in the connection option;
2. Use **mqtts** protocol;
3. For the **username** option, use {iothubhostname}/{device_id}/api-version=2016-11-14, where {iothubhostname} is the full CName of the IoT hub.
4. For the **password** field, use a SAS token. You can use [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/tools/DeviceExplorer) to get the SAS token. The SAS token **must be generated** using a policy which involves the permissions: "registry write", "service connect" and "device connect" (a combination of less than these three might work, but providing "registry write" is not enough for sure).

See here for more details: [Using the MQTT protocol directly (as a device)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device)

Comment: Thanks :) but this gives `Error: Connection refused: Server unavailable`.

Comment: @TPPZ Works for me. Check your SAS / username. A malformed username leads to Server Unavailable for me too.

Comment: @Michael Xu What's the structure of the SAS token you are using? Which fields are defined in the key/values? The same credentials that are not working for this Javascript example, are working instead for the Python code using Paho and the digicert certificate I've copied from the first element of the array at https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/certs/certs.c (as shown in the official docs)

Comment: Ok, I got this working using a different policy (username) with different permissions. It seems the permissions: "service connect" and "device connect" (either one or the other or both) must be provided. I was trying with permission "registry write" (which I think includes "registry read") thinking that was enough.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. Could you give example on the 'subscribe'? I could not find example of the subscribe in the `async.mqtt` library

Comment: @LeonardAB, a device should subscribe using `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#` as a Topic Filter to receive messages from IoT Hub. Please refer to [Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly).

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT thanks. I tried to modify the code above by adding this inside the `doStuff` : `await client.publish(iotHubTopic, "It works!"); await client.subscribe(iotHubTopic2);  client.on('message', function (topic, message) {   console.log(message.toString())     });    await client.end();  console.log("Done");` where `iotHubTopic2` is `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#`. However this does not show anything on the console. Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After trying for half n hour, I came to know that one of my colleague had disabled my device on Iothub.