# Azure IoT Hub simple publish/subscribe in node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, mqtt.js

Hello I am trying to create a simple communication using Azure IoT hub in node.js.
I am using `mqtt` library. With the help of the [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711853/connect-to-azure-iothub-using-mqtt-in-javascript) I was able to connect to the IoT hub, but I do not receive the message I send. Here is the code (the `client = mqtt.connect` part is skipped as I assume it works)

subscriber.js

```
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to Azure IoT Hub');
  client.subscribe(iotHubTopic, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error subscribing to topic:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Subscribed to topic:', iotHubTopic);
    }
  });
});

client.on('message', (iotHubTopic, message) => {
  console.log('Received message:', message.toString());
});
```

publisher.js

```
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to Azure IoT Hub');
  const message = {
    data: 'Hello from the device!'
  };
  client.publish(iotHubTopic, JSON.stringify(message), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error publishing message:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Message published to topic:', iotHubTopic);
    }
    client.end();
  });
});
```

I run `subscriber.js` and it writes to console both, 'connected' and 'subscribed' console logs. Then I run `publisher.js` and it logs also both 'connected' and 'published'. But after the message is published after few seconds in the subscriber terminal it **again** logs 'connected' and 'subscribed' as if the `client.on('connect', ...)` was called again.

I will appreciate any help or suggestions.

EDIT:
As I found out the intended use of the Auzre IoT Hub is different and is more oriented on the request/response communication. For publish/subscribe communication it is possible to use [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions?tabs=connection-string).

Comment: Have a look at the following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support Note, that the Azure IoT Hub is not a generic MQTT Broker.

Comment: Hello @Riomare in publisher.js you are sending the data to the IoT Hub device, in subscriber.js you are Receiving messages from the IoT Hub device. It can be done by mqqt and Azure IoT Hub. Could you why are using iotHubTopic? I was able to send and receive without using iotHubTopic.

Comment: @Sampath It was just my bad understanding of the usage of IoT Hub as it is not the right MQTT broker as I thought it is. I am new to this and I thought IoT Hub works as a broker between subs and pubs. But now I know that IoT Hub is more like request/response broker than publish/subscribe broker.

Comment: @Sampath As I was reading first articles about MQTT and IoT communication, I believed that (in simple words) devices pusblish data to some topis to the broker and broker sends the data to all subscribers of that topic. But now I know it does not work like this here.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to connect to IoT Hub using connection string.

- While using below I was not able connect and connection to IoT hub.

```
iotHubTopic = devices/${deviceId}/messages/events/
```

But by using connection string, [MQTT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support) without iotHubTopic .I was able to connect, send message and receiving Message from the IoT Hub. reference from  @ [kgremban](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-5.md),[jlian](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-mqtt-5-preview-samples-csharp/commits?author=jlian)

- Connection to IoT Hub

```js
const { Client } = require('azure-iot-device');
const  Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
// Replace with your connection string and device ID
const  connectionString = 'Your Iot Hub connection srtring ';
const  deviceId = 'DeviceId';
// Create a new IoT Hub client
const  client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);
// Open a connection to the IoT Hub
client.open((err) => {
if (err) {
console.error('Error opening IoT Hub connection:', err);
} else {
console.log('IoT Hub connection opened');
}
});
```

[image]

- Send the message to IoT Hub.

```js
const { Client } = require('azure-iot-device');
const  Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
const { Message } = require('azure-iot-device');
// Replace with your connection string and device ID
const  connectionString = 'your device connection string ';
const  deviceId = 'Your DeviceID';
// Create a new IoT Hub client
const  client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);
client.open((err) => {
if (err) {
console.error('Error opening IoT Hub connection:', err);
} else {
console.log('IoT Hub connection opened');
// Send a message to the IoT device
const  message = new  Message(JSON.stringify({
data:  'Hello from the cloud!'
}));
console.log('Sending message:', message.getData());
client.sendEvent(message, (err, res) => {
if (err) {
console.error('Error sending message:', err);
} else {
console.log('Message sent to IoT device with status:', res.constructor.name);
}
client.close();
});
}
});
```

- Receiving Message from the IoT Hub.

```js
const { Client } = require('azure-iot-device');
const  Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
const { Message } = require('azure-iot-device');
// Replace with your connection string and device ID
const  connectionString = 'your device connection string';
const  deviceId = 'DeviceId';
// Create a new IoT Hub client
const  client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);
client.open((err) => {
if (err) {
console.error('Error opening IoT Hub connection:', err);
} else {
console.log('IoT Hub connection opened');
// Listen for incoming messages from the device
client.on('message', (msg) => {
console.log('Received message from device:', msg.getData().toString());
});
}
});
```

For more information refer [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-mqtt-5-preview-samples-csharp)

[image]

[image]